# Simplify $\sum n(n+1)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation

According to WolframAlpha,

$$\sum_{n=1}^k n(n+1)=\frac{1}{3}k(k+1)(k+2)$$

and it is easy to verify this if we use induction.

However, I would like to know how one can actually come up with this, other than by thinking about how to force the terms to cancel out.

I tried: Since $k(k+1)/2=1+2+\cdots+k$,

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^k n(n+1) &= 2\bigg(1(k)+2(k-1)+3(k-2)+\cdots+k(1)\bigg)\\
& = 2\sum_{n=1}^k n(k-n+1)\\
\sum_{n=1}^k n(n+1) &= 2\bigg(1(k)+2(k-1)+3(k-2)+\cdots+k(k-(k-1))\bigg)\\
& = 2\bigg( (1+2+3+\cdots+k)k-(0\cdot1+1\cdot2+2\cdot3+\cdots+(k-1)k) \bigg)\\
& = k^2(k+1)-2\sum_{n=1}^{k-1} n(n+1)\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^k (-2)^{k-n}n^2(n+1)
\end{align}$$

I feel like I'm only making it worse..

Comment: You can also use the sums of $n^2$ and $n$ (both from $1$ to $k$) to get the result. Deriving those sums works considering that the sum must be a polynomial with a degree which is $1$ higher than the occuring exponent. This leads to Faulhaber's formulas.

Comment: If you are familiar with binomial coefficients $\binom{a}{b}$ which counts the number of ways of choosing a subset of size $b$ from an $a$-element set, by dividing both sides of the identity by $2$ you can recognize these terms as being binomial coefficients.  There are $\binom{k+2}{3}=\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3\cdot 2}$ ways to pick a subset of size three from a $k+2$-element set.  On the left, we broke apart into cases based on what the largest number was and pick two more from those numbers smaller.  Since both approaches correctly count the same scenario they must be equal.

Comment: Looking at an expression, interpreting it as an answer to a counting problem, coming up with a counting problem with that as an answer, and then finding a different approach to solving the same counting problem is a powerful technique known as "combinatorial proof" and is often seen as "mathematically elegant."  No long messy algebraic manipulations needed.  In problems like yours, seeing both sides of the identity gives strong hints as to what sort of scenarios we want to count, but starting with only one side and not seeing the other we could still have used this to find a second side.

Comment: For example, with your problem we could have broken apart based on the *middle* element of the $3$-element subset to show this is also equal to $2\sum\limits_{n=1}^kn(k-n+1)$

Answer (score 3):

Your solution is very close. Your last calculation shows
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^{k}n(n+1)=k^2(k+1)-2\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}n(n+1).
\end{equation}
The sums on the left and right side are almost the same, except for the coefficient and the limits of summation. If you note
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k-1}n(n+1)=\sum_{n=1}^{k}n(n+1)-k(k+1),$$
then you can immediately write the first identity as
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{k}n(n+1)&=k^2(k+1)-2\sum_{n=1}^{k}n(n+1)+2k(k+1)\\
&=k(k+1)(k+2)-2\sum_{n=1}^{k}n(n+1).
\end{align}
Now, both sides have your desired sum $\sum_{n=1}^{k}n(n+1)$, which you can solve for and you have your result.

Answer (score 1):

*A possible way to do it*
$$S_n=\sum_{n=1}^k n(n+1) x^n=\sum_{n=1}^k \big[n(n-1)+2n \big]x^n=\sum_{n=1}^k n(n-1) x^n+2\sum_{n=1}^k n x^n$$
$$S_n=x^2\sum_{n=1}^k n(n-1) x^{n-2}+2x\sum_{n=1}^k n x^{n-1}$$
$$S_n=x^2\Big[\sum_{n=1}^k  x^{n}\Big]''+2x\Big[\sum_{n=1}^k  x^{n}\Big]'$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^k  x^{n}=\frac{x \left(x^k-1\right)}{x-1}$$ Compute the derivatives, simplify and look at the limit when $x\to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the sum backwards:

$$\frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{3}-n(n+1)$$

$$=\frac{(n-1)n(n+1)}{3}$$

etc...

Answer (score 0):

If $p$ is a polynomial of degree $d$ and $$P(k)=\sum_{n=1}^kp(n)$$ then $P$ is a polynomial of degree $d+1$. So evaluating $P$ at $d+2$ points gives you $d+2$ equations in the coefficients of $P$.

A simpler example: $p(n)=n$. Say $P(k)=Ak^2+Bk+C$. Then $$A+B+C=P(1)=1,$$ $$4A+2B+C=P(2)=3,$$ and $$9A+3B+C=P(3)=6$$; this leads to $A=B=1/2$, $C=0$, hence $P(n)=n(n+1)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $n(n+1) = 2\bigg(\frac{n(n+1)}{2!}\bigg)=2\binom{n+1}{2}$. Then the sum becomes ....
$$\begin{align}
S(k) &= \sum_{n=1}^k{n(n+1)}\\
&= 2\sum_{n=1}^k{\binom{n+1}{2}}\\
(1) &= 2\binom{k+2}{3}\\
&= 2\cdot\frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3!}\\
&= \frac{k(k+1)(k+2)}{3}\\
\end{align}$$

Where $(1)$ is just the hockey-stick identity.